# How to prove 3n + 2log n = O(n)

Tags: math, big-o

How would I be able to prove 3n + 2log n = O(n) using the definition of big-O?

The C is supposedly 6, & the k is 1, but I have no idea how that is found.  Much help will greatly be appreciated.

Comment: [`What have you tried?`](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Did you compute the limit of `(3n+2log n)/n` when `n -> oo` (i.e. n tending to infinity)? And if you did, this is the wrong place to ask.

Answer (score 6):

To formally prove this result, you need to find a choice of n<sub>0</sub> and c such that

> For any n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>: 3n + 2log n ≤ cn

To start this off, note that if you have any n ≥ 1, then log n < n.  Consequently, if you consider any n ≥ 1, you have that

> 3n + 2log n < 3n + 2n = 5n

Consequently, if you pick n<sub>0</sub> = 1 and c = 5, you have that

> For any n ≥ n0: 3n + 2log n < 3n + 2n = 5n ≤ cn

And therefore 3n + 2 log n = O(n).

More generally, when given problems like these, try identifying the dominant term (here, the n term) and trying to find some choice of n<sub>0</sub> such that the non-dominant terms are overwhelmed by the dominant term.  Once you've done this, all that's left to do is choose the right constant c.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess (your question is quite unclear): the task is to show that

```
O(3n + 2log n) = O(n)
```

Now that's how it comes out: `n -> n` grows faster than `n -> log n`, and since the complexity is **asymptotic,** only the fastest-growing term matters, which is `n` in this case.

Comment: I think that the OP wants to formally prove that 3n + 2log n = O(n) by using the definition of big-O notation (hence the n0 and c).

Comment: @templatetypedef Then he just calculates `lim (n->inf) (3n + 2log n) / n` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can prove the following if I remember correctly: 
if f1(n)=O(g1(n)), f2(n)=O(g2(n)) then f1(n)+f2(n)=O(max{g1(n),g2(n)}).
From there it's pretty straight forward.